# Resultset throws syntax error when there are no records in database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Below I show my sql query which is dynamic in Java.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -365);
```

> Adjust to 12 months before current month with 0 hrs and min

```
cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), 1, 0, 0, 0);
String lastYearTime = String.valueOf(cal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000);

while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        tablename = Database.getTableName((String)iterator.next());
        fields = "status,count(*) as count";
        query.append("select " + fields + " from " + tablename + " where");
        query.append(" toid ='" + collegeId + "'");
        query.append(" and dtstamp >='" + lastYearTime + "'");
        query.append(" group by status");
        if(i.hasNext())
            query.append(" UNION ");
    }
    StringBuffer countquery = new StringBuffer("select status, SUM(count) as count from ( " + query + ")as temp  group by status ");

    ResultSet rs = Database.executeQuery(countquery.toString(), connection);
```

In the above query, tablename will be random based on other factors. collegeId can be any id. Status can be like dropout,pursuing or any random status.

When I execute my above query, result set works fine and data is displayed. But when there are no records in the database then it throws a sql syntax error 1064 stating

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')as temp  group by status' at line 1

Comment: You shouldn't concatenate values into a query. Use a prepared statement with parameter placeholders. Your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: There should be no difference between presence of data in the database or not, because syntax errors happen **before** a query gets executed. More likely the problem happens when you construct a query when `iterator` doesn't have any results, as then `query` is probably an empty string. Unfortunately you don't show enough code to confirm that. You start by debugging your code, printing out the resulting query, and update your question with more code and the actually produced query.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem1**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')as temp  group by status' at line 1
```

You have a problem in your query:

```
select status, SUM(count) as count from ( " + query + ")as temp  group by status
```

You should to make a space in your query here :

```
from ( " + query + ")as
```

replace this `")as` with this `") as`

**EDIT**

**Problem2**

```
SQL Exception : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as temp group by status' at line 1 SQL State : 42000 Error Code : 1064
```

Your query is a `String` so you should to put it between two `'query'`

now replace this :

```
select status, SUM(count) as count from ( " + query + ")as temp  group by status
```

By this :

```
select status, SUM(count) as count from ( '" + query + "') as temp  group by status
```

Good luck.

Comment: i think the error is changes now, can you please post what you get now, or you get the same problem?

Comment: Syntax Error 1064

Comment: you see, so now please post all you error so we can help you :)

Comment: SQL Exception : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as temp  group by status' at line 1 SQL State : 42000 Error Code : 1064

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur efforts. I still get the syntax error---SQL Exception : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''') as temp  group by status' at line 1 SQL State : 42000 Error Code : 1064

Comment: can you make `Systeme.out.print(query)` to see how the query look like?

Comment: @Tatkal and i you can also show us how `countquery` look like

Comment: select status, SUM(count) as count from ('') as temp  group by status

Comment: If you have a case that your query can be empty then you can test your query before you use it like this `if(query not empty) use this` else `use this`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try with different tecnniques . if anything works then i'll let u know

Comment: if(query.length>0)
{
  // display data
}
else
{
  // no data to display
}

Answer (score 0):

> Resultset throws syntax error when there are no records in database

No it doesn't. It throws a syntax-error exception when you have a syntax error in your query.

Comment: Syntax Error 1064